# Zend Framework 2: Unable to render template - with a twist

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I know that there are many questions and answeres to "Unable to render template" but my question has a twist.

When I open this URL: `http://localhost:8080/users/usermanager/index`

I get this error: `Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "users/user-manager/index"; resolver could not resolve to a file`

Which is totally fine as I have renamed `user-manager` to `usermanager`. I have grepped my entire code and can not find any reference to `user-manager` anymore. Why is Zend still searching for it?

My module.config.php:

```
<?php

namespace Users;

return array (
        'controllers' => array (
                'invokables' => array (
                        'Users\Controller\Index' => 'Users\Controller\IndexController',
                        'Users\Controller\Register' => 'Users\Controller\RegisterController',
                        'Users\Controller\Login' => 'Users\Controller\LoginController',
                        'Users\Controller\UserManager' => 'Users\Controller\UserManagerController' 
                ) 
        ),

        'router' => array (
                'routes' => array (
                        'users' => array (
                                'type' => 'Literal',
                                'options' => array (
                                        'route' => '/users',
                                        'defaults' => array (
                                                '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Users\Controller',
                                                'controller' => 'Index',
                                                'action' => 'index' 
                                        ) 
                                ),
                                'may_terminate' => true,
                                'child_routes' => array (
                                        'default' => array (
                                                'type' => 'Segment',
                                                'options' => array (
                                                        'route' => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                                                        'constraints' => array (
                                                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*' 
                                                        ),
                                                        'defaults' => array () 
                                                ) 
                                        ) 
                                ) 
                        ),
                        'usermanager' => array (
                                'type' => 'Segment',
                                'options' => array (
                                        'route' => '/usermanager[/:action[/:id]]',
                                        'constraints' => array (
                                                'action' => '[a-zA-z][a-zA-z0-0_-]*',
                                                'id' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*' 
                                        ),
                                        'defaults' => array (
                                                'controller' => 'Users\Controller\UserManager',
                                                'action' => 'index' 
                                        ) 
                                ) 
                        ) 
                ) 
        ),
        'service_manager' => array (
                'abstract_factories' => array (
                        'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
                        'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory' 
                ),
                'aliases' => array (
                        'translator' => 'MvcTranslator' 
                ) 
        ),
        'translator' => array (
                'translation_file_patterns' => array (
                        array (
                                'type' => 'gettext',
                                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                                'pattern' => '%s.mo',
                                'text_domain' => __NAMESPACE__ 
                        ) 
                ) 
        ),
        'view_manager' => array (
                'template_path_stack' => array (
                        'users' => __DIR__ . '/../view' 
                ) 
        ) 
);
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you also have to change `UserManager` to `Usermanager`.

Zend2 automatically translate `StrningsLikeThis` to `strings-like-this` when it comes to search for default views.

Comment: Thanks! I would have never ever found this by my own.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use template names out of the naming convention you could create a template_map like so:

> module.config.php

```
view_manager' => array(
   ...   
   'template_map' => array(
      'users/user-manager/index'  => __DIR__ . '/../view/users/user-manager/index.phtml',
   ...
```

I personally just stick with the convention since creating these map's is somewhat of a hassle.

Comment: Template_map are much more performant, so it's a good thing to use them. And you can generate them : just look at `vendor/bin` if you use Composer or `zendframework/bin`